# How to handle payment gateway in my ionic App?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, payment-gateway

Now iam working with payment gateway from [tracknpay.com](https://www.traknpay.com/).

**payment.ts**

```
 payment(){
  var paymentdata={
  'api_key':'xxxx',
  'order_id':'11111111111124',
  'mode':'TEST', 
  'amount':200,

  'currency':'INR',

  'description':'BLABLA',
  'name':'Ajith',

  'email':'ajith@gmail.com',

  'phone':'8086502009',
  'city':'tvm',

  'country':'IND',

  'zip_code':'695505',
  'return_url':'http://viarchtechnologies.com/',
  'hash':'B1AA86BF8108702CAE54C2F5C017BCB36F6C47EFF9CB74A840938EA3AD0E88BBD8638A17F0F5B0D62DDDBABFC79C242281220CD12449D371676CAF3F44D1DD4F' 
  }
  console.log(paymentdata)
  return this.http.post('https://biz.traknpay.in/v2/paymentrequest',paymentdata).map(res=>res.text()).subscribe(res=>
{
  console.log(res)
 // const browser = this.iab.create('https://ionicframework.com/');
  window.open("https://biz.traknpay.in/v2/paymentrequest")
},
    err=>{
      console.log(err)
        })

}
```

And I got the success response as payment page html template.And i have also doubt about the return_url.how can i redirect to their payment page and complete the payment process.

Comment: "console.log(res)" means you have done the payment.
and where you want to redirect after getting the response from api?

Comment: @AnkitPandey After getting the response i have to redirect to tracknpay payment request page.

Comment: See the https://www.traknpay.com/developers.html#plugins

Comment: $('form[name="tnpForm"] input[name="hash"]').val(response.data);
    $('form[name="tnpForm"]').attr("action", "https://biz.traknpay.in/v1/paymentrequest");
                form.submit();     
    }

Comment: Download node.js plugin or any other which compatible to your application.
And run that folder (just for testing).